# Delete file in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to delete file in assembly code (NASM) but I experienced the error "relocation truncated to fit against data" on section "mov dx, file_name". FYI, the file that I was trying to delete "input.txt" file do exist in my folder. I am not so sure with this kind of issue. Let me know where I missed.

```
section .data
; filename
file_name           DB  "input.txt"

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    nop
    mov dx, file_name   ; getting an error : relocation truncated to fit R_386_16 against .data
    mov ah,41h          ; function 41h - delete file
    int 21h             ; call DOS service

endIt:
    nop
    ;Exit the program back to linux legally
    mov eax, 1                  ; exit system call value
    mov ebx, 0                  ; exit return code
    int 80h                     ; Call the kernel
```

Comment: You can't use 16-bit MS-DOS functions in a Linux executable. You need to use a Linux system call to delete the file, the same way you use a Linux system call to exit the program.

Comment: That error message refers specifically to your effort to load label offset into 16b register, while you are in 32b mode where memory offsets are 32b. Would you do `mov edx,file_name`, it would compile without warning (but it would not work, because `int 21h` under linux doesn't work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, to remove a file (in UNIX jargon, to “unlink” a file), you need to use the system call `unlink`. Its sole argument is a pointer to the file name to unlink, it returns 0 on success, a negative value on error. The system call number for `unlink` on i386 is 10, so to invoke `unlink`, write code like this:

```
mov eax, 10        ; system call 10: unlink
mov ebx, file_name ; file name to unlink
int 80h            ; call into the system
```

The file name should be a NUL terminated C string. You can make a C string by appending `,0` to your string:

```
file_name    DB  "input.txt",0
```

Note that this system call cannot be used to unlink directories. To remove directories (here “removed” is used as removing directories is on traditional file systems more involved than just unlinking them), you need to use the `rmdir` system call, which has number 40 and the same arguments and return value.